# Get Notification when new user added in azure active directory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

i have created one application that get all users details from azure Active directory using graph api bt i need when new user added in organization give notification in my application any service or available for that or not.
thanks in advance.

i have already created check all user count and check after every some time but its not reliable solution any other solution i need for that.

Comment: How are you checking the use count? I mean have you created a webjob or logic app for that?

Comment: i have checked that from graph api but its done, but question is its not reliable way any other solution are there or not?

Comment: You can go with WebJob because that's what it is supposed to do

Comment: notification display in my web application